# Append and remove tabs using sidebarPanel

Tags: r, button, shiny

Having trouble deleting tabs that have been newly created in Shiny.

Scenario:

1. Add new tab "A"
2. Add new tab "B"
3. Click delete on tab B - doesn't delete
4. Select tab A, click delete it works

I feel its something to do with ids, stumped with the logic.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = "Test", id="tabs",             
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("testlist", "Select test:", 
                                    list("A", "B", "C")),
                        actionButton("append", "New tab")),
                     
                      mainPanel()
             )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

tabnamesinput<-reactive({
                         input$testlist
                        })
  
  
observeEvent(input$append,{
  id<-paste0(tabnamesinput()) 
  appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
            tabPanel(id,
                     sidebarPanel(
                       actionButton("remove", "Delete")
                     )
  )
  )
})

observeEvent(input$remove,{
  removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your above approach you are trying to assign the same `id = "remove"` to each delete-button. This won't work. Every button needs it's own `id`.

Once each button has it's unique id you need an observer listening to all events triggered by those buttons. The following looks for all inputs matching the pattern `"^remove_"`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = "Test", id = "tabs",             
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("testlist", "Select test:", list("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"),
                        actionButton("append", "New tab")),
                      mainPanel()
             )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$append,{
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(input$testlist,
                       sidebarPanel(
                         actionButton(paste0("remove_", input$testlist), "Delete")
                       )
              )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(lapply(grep(pattern = "^remove_", x = names(input), value = TRUE), function(x){input[[x]]}),{
    if(input$tabs != "Home"){
      removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
      updateSelectInput(session, "testlist", selected = input$testlist) # keep the selection when re-rendering sidebarPanel
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. Your gif/video is brilliant!